# Looking for a bash script to run a program with different inputs on linux server

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

I knew how to write that bash once, but I can't figure it out anymore.

As the title says, it should be script aimed at running on a Linux server.

My goal is to do those commands without having it typed again and again.
(I'm chaining the input files in each run.)

```
bsprun -npes 1 ./a.out file1.txt file2.txt
bsprun -npes 2 ./a.out file1.txt file2.txt
bsprun -npes 3 ./a.out file1.txt file2.txt
bsprun -npes 4 ./a.out file1.txt file2.txt
bsprun -npes 5 ./a.out file1.txt file2.txt
bsprun -npes 6 ./a.out file1.txt file2.txt
bsprun -npes 7 ./a.out file1.txt file2.txt
bsprun -npes 8 ./a.out file1.txt file2.txt
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, after reading your description a bit more closely, perhaps you want this:

```
#!/bin/bash

bsprun -npes "$1" ./a.out "$2" "$3"
```

`chmod +x` the script then call it like

```
./myscript 1 file1.txt file2.txt
./myscript 2 file2.txt file3.txt
./myscript 3 file4.txt file5.txt
...
```

If your input files change according to a pattern we could make the script a bit smarter but it is unclear what your file names look like.

<del>To get the exact output you posted, put it in a loop like:</del>

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in {1..8}; do
  bsprun -npes $i ./a.out file1.txt file2.txt
done
```

Comment: and how do i run that ? with source ?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it continually, use this:

```
  #!/bin/bash

i="1"

while true;
do
    if [ $i -eq 9]; then
       i=1
    fi
    bsprun -npes $i ./a.out file1.txt file2.txt
    i = `expr $i + 1`
done
```

Comment: You have spaces before and after the `i` at the bottom of the loop.  Also, `expr` has been deprecated, instead use `i=$((i + 1))`

Comment: @SigeX, thx. I actually typed it in the 'answer window' and didn't notice it.

Comment: You need a space before the `]` (or you could do `if ((i == 9))`). Here is a simpler version of your script: `while true; do for i in {1..9}; do bsprun ...; done; done` - no need to manage the variable yourself. You could also do `... do for ((i=1; i<=limit; i++)); do ...`. By the way, instead of using `expr`, you could have used `((i++))`.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to learn to write BASH, you may want to take a look at

https://github.com/37signals/sub

its helped me a lot with keeping my scripts organized

also google is your friend

```
bash script loop example
```

the above search returns a ton of results exactly what you are looking for

Comment: Unfortunately, when it comes to bash, the internet is full of bad examples and bad practices. I'd say that google is your worst friend when looking information about bash.